# Should I release NSBundle in sound?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

Should I release `NSBundle` in the below code or not? `NSURL` should also be release or not?
I am confused.

```
NSBundle  *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSError   *error;
NSURL     *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[mainBundle pathForResource:@"count_in" ofType: @"mp3"]];
AVAudioPlayer *player1 = [(AVAudioPlayer*) [AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&error];
self.player =   player1;
[self.player play];
[player1 release];
```

Comment: What is the point of creating and passing in an error object if you don't perform any error handling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not release `NSBundle`  and `NSURL` instances because you haven't alloced these.

**From the apple Documentation.**

> You take ownership of an object if you create it using a method whose
>   name begins with “alloc”, “new”,
>   “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example,
>   alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy), or
>   if you send it a retain message.
>
> You use release or autorelease to relinquish ownership of an object.
>   autorelease just means “send a release
>   message in the future” (specifically:
>   when the used autorelease pool
>   receives a drain message—to understand
>   when this will be, see “Autorelease
>   Pools”).

I would highly recommend you to clear your memory management concept.

Read the apple article on
[Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)

Comment: @Umair_uas, why are you worried about memory?  Are you getting memory warnings?

Comment: NSBundle is a singleton and should not take up too much memory. If it does, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I found in instrument "General block" when i click on it there is a huge [NSBundle mainBundle] allocation on device. Thats why i am scare. I am hitting sound 200 to 400 times in my app. Sound file is mp3 and small in length.

Comment: @Umair_uas :you should not be worried about the object which you get from framework,In your case they NSBundle and NSURL instances,suggest to go through the link in answer.